# Autocomplete DropDownChoice

Tags: java, autocomplete, wicket, dropdownchoice

I am looking for the simplest way to apply autocomplete to a wicket 8 dropdownchoice with a list of names.

I just want a hint..

```
List<User> list = getUsers();

final DropDownChoice<User> dropdown = new DropDownChoice<User>("dropdown",
                new PropertyModel<User>(this, "selected"), list, renderer) { //code };
```

Answer (score 0):

DropDownChoice component produces plain HTML `<select>` element.

Your options are:

1. use JavaScript library that converts plain HTML Select elements to autocompleter like [Select2.js](https://select2.org/), [Chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and similar. You can use [WicketStuff-Select2](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/select2-parent) or just do `$.select2('#yourSelectId')` manually
2. use Wicket-Extensions [AutoCompleteTextField](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/138abdd0ecb05947d42385db22982f3a42439e16/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/AutoCompleteTextField.java) instead of DropDownChoice

Answer (score 0):

I am using this piece of code but I am not sure if it works well..

```
dropdown.add(new AutoCompleteBehavior(new StringAutoCompleteRenderer()){
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected Iterator getChoices(String input) {
                    List<String> completions = new ArrayList();
                    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext()){
                        String user  = ((User) iter.next()).getAddress();
                        if(user.startsWith(input)){
                            completions.add(user);
                        }
                    }                   
                    return completions.iterator();
                }               
            });
```